# How to add twitter tracking code to a Drupal site?

Tags: 7

Twitter now creates code to track visits to your site from twitter.  https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170807-conversion-tracking-for-websites#

Where would be the best place to put this code, into a template? is there a module for this like there is for google analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to use [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) in your template.php or a custom module. But there's also a module out there to accomplish this task:

Take a look at the module [Tracking Code](https://www.drupal.org/project/tracking_code). It allows you to inject arbitrary code inside `<HEAD>`, after `<BODY>` or before `</BODY>`.